# Looking for help filtering Gmail results

Tags: gmail, search-operators

Is there a way to filter Gmail results to exclude results where a search term appears only in certain contexts?

I spend a lot of time looking for results related to state taxes, so I monitor a lot of think tanks and the like using the terms "state" and "tax." Unfortunately, I end up getting a lot results where "state" is triggered only because someone is talking about the United States. Similarly, I try to filter e-mails based on whether they include the word "tax," but then everything gets by if it mentions that "your donation is tax-exempt."

I'd like to find a way to further filter these, but simply doing a -"United States" or -"tax-deductible" is too heavy-handed, because I may want an e-mail that discusses taxes but also uses the "tax-exempt" language.

For example, I would want a search to return "The United States has 50 states," but I'd want it to exclude "The United States is awesome."

Is there any way to do this with Boolean operators? I'm guessing it would be easy enough with regular expressions, but as far as I can tell, Gmail doesn't support it (also: I don't actually know regex.)

Comment: The linked duplicate doesn't seem to do anything to answer this question. None of the operators in that answer show how to return results only if a word appears outside of a given phrase, regardless of whether that phrase is in the result?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to surround the individual words with quotes, i.e.

```
"state" "tax"
```

This way, you're not removing results (using `-"United States" -"tax-deductible"`) simply because they contain those phrases.

Adding quotes around single words prioritizes them in your search to Google.

Here's [the search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22state%22%20%22tax%22&safe=off) for `"state" "tax"`, which appears to give you what you want: targeted results on state taxes. Clicking on the [News](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22state%22%20%22tax%22&safe=off&tbm=nws) option of the search might be even better for you.